# Как сделать окно без панели в tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Мне нужно,чтобы было окно, но на нём не было панели вообще. Ни иконки, ни панели закрыть свернуть окно, ни названия, ни верхней части. Также чтобы кликом мыши можно было перетянуть окно по экрану. И если не сложно, сделать кнопку закрыть внизу экрана. Заранее очень благодарен!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53647256/2101808

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53647256/2101808)

```
from tkinter import *

class Grip:
    ''' Makes a window dragable. '''
    def __init__ (self, parent, disable=None, releasecmd=None) :
        self.parent = parent
        self.root = parent.winfo_toplevel()

        self.disable = disable
        if type(disable) == 'str':
            self.disable = disable.lower()

        self.releaseCMD = releasecmd

        self.parent.bind('<Button-1>', self.relative_position)
        self.parent.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self.drag_unbind)

    def relative_position (self, event) :
        cx, cy = self.parent.winfo_pointerxy()
        geo = self.root.geometry().split("+")
        self.oriX, self.oriY = int(geo[1]), int(geo[2])
        self.relX = cx - self.oriX
        self.relY = cy - self.oriY

        self.parent.bind('<Motion>', self.drag_wid)

    def drag_wid (self, event) :
        cx, cy = self.parent.winfo_pointerxy()
        d = self.disable
        x = cx - self.relX
        y = cy - self.relY
        if d == 'x' :
            x = self.oriX
        elif d == 'y' :
            y = self.oriY
        self.root.geometry('+%i+%i' % (x, y))

    def drag_unbind (self, event) :
        self.parent.unbind('<Motion>')
        if self.releaseCMD != None :
            self.releaseCMD()

def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("200x200")
    root.resizable(0, 0)
    root.overrideredirect(1)

    back = Frame(root, bg="grey")
    back.pack_propagate(0)
    back.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

    top_Frame = Frame(back, bg="#505050")
    top_Frame.place(x=0, y=0, anchor="nw", width=200, height=20)
    '''Would Be great if it could be specified to only be moved
    when dragging with the Frame above.'''
    grip = Grip(top_Frame)

    Ext_but = Button(top_Frame, text="X", bg="#FF6666", fg="white", command=lambda: exit())
    Ext_but.place(x=170, y=0, anchor="nw", width=30, height=20)

    root.mainloop()

main()
```